# How do I add a line break after every 5 fifth semicolon (;) in a text file

Tags: text-processing

The file looks like this (one big line):

```
a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a; etc......
```

Now I want to cut the text and do a line break after every fifth semicolon (`;`) so it looks like this:

```
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
etc....
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 18):

With `tr` and `paste`

```
tr ';' '\n' < semicolons | paste -d';' - - - - -
```

Tests

```
$ cat semicolons
a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a

$ tr ';' '\n' < semicolons | paste -d';'  - - - - -
a;a;a;a;a
a;a;a;a;a
a;a;a;a;a
a;a;a;a;a
a;a;a;a;a
a;a;a;a;a
a;a;a;a;a
a;a;a;a;a
a;a;a;a;a
```

Both [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) and [`paste`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) are specified in POSIX standard.

To add the required semicolon `;` at the end of the lines

```
tr ';' '\n' < semicolons | paste -d';' - - - - - | sed s/$/\;/
```

Tests

```
$ tr ';' '\n' < semicolons | paste -d';' - - - - - | sed s/$/\;/
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
```

Comment: good one. Alternately `tr ';' '\n' < semicolons | paste -sd';;;;\n'`

Comment: @iruvar Good catch ;)

Answer (score 13):

Purely using GNU `sed` substitution:

```bsh
sed 's/\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}\)/\1\n/g'
```

or without all the escaping backslashes using `-E` (thanks @JoL):

```bsh
sed -E 's/(([^;]*;){5})/\1\n/g'
```

Example:

```bsh
$ cat test.txt
a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a;a; etc......

$ cat test.txt | sed 's/\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}\)/\1\n/g'
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a;a;
a;a;a;a; etc......
```

Explanation:

- `\([^;]*;\)`: regex capture group matching all characters up to and including a semi-colon.
- `\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}\)`: regex capture group matching five occurrences of the above. In the `sed` command, this will be matched into `\1`.
- `s/\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}\)/\1\n/g`: substitute (`s/`) every occurrence (`/g`) of the group of five occurrences of all characters up to and including a semicolon (`\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}\)`) with itself (`\1`), but followed by a newline character (`\n`).

Comment: Also Thanks!!! Solved!

Comment: You can skip the backslashes in the pattern by using `-r` (GNU option) or `-E` (GNU and POSIX option). I.e. `sed -E 's/(([^;]*;){5})/\1\n/g'`

Answer (score 5):

Sed editor method we place a newline after the 5th semicolon, print upto the newline, remove upto newline, rinse n repeat till you run out of the pattern space.

```
$ sed -e 's/;/;\n/5;P;D' file
```

With Perl, use semicolon as field separator and print in bunches of 5 with semicolons as OFS and an empty field at the end to get the trailing semicolon printed :

```
$ perl -F\; -lane '$,=";";
     print splice(@F, 0, 5), q() while @F;
' file
```

Using Awk we look at a bunch of 5 fields and append a semicolon to the first 4 and semicolon + newline to the fifth. Then print the fields with a null separating them:

```
$ awk -F\; -vOFS= '{
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            $(i) = $(i) (i%5 ? FS : FS RS)
  }1' file
```

Comment: Upvoted for impressive Sed and Perl solutions (the Awk solution prints an extraneous semi-colon at the very end).

Answer (score 0):

I find that while regexes are appropriate for this kind of task, I always do it with text editor macros for the visual help and simplicity.

Using vim, you can

```
set textwidth=20
```

or similarly low and

```
set wrap
```

and if the file really needs editing, a simple macro like

```
qqf;f;f;f;f;i\n99999@q
```

would do it.